# Qt has not been ported to this OS

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile my `c++` project with Cross ARM GCC in eclipse.

I installed `GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-ins` (as described [here](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/plugins/install/#eclipse--cdt)), installed `libqt4-dev` by running `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`, and included the Qt libraries into my project:

```
/usr/include/qt4
/usr/include/qt4/Qt
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui
```

(`Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross ARM C++ Compiler > Includes`)

and:

```
QtCore
QtGui
```

(`Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross ARM C++ Linker > Libraries`)

Running `qmake` succeeds and creates a `Makefile`.

But I can't build my project.

Here's my code (which compiles and runs fine using `make all` under default compiler, and not `Cross ARM GCC`):

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setGeometry(0,0,mainWindow.getButtonWidth(),mainWindow.getButtonHeight()*mainWindow.getButtonsNum());
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    int getButtonWidth();
    int getButtonHeight();
    int getButtonsNum();
    ~MainWindow(){}
private:
    QPushButton *button1, *button2, *button3, *button4;
    const int ButtonWidth = 200;
    const int ButtonHeight = 50;
    const int ButtonsNum = 4;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    button1 = new QPushButton("Button1", this);
    button2 = new QPushButton("Button2", this);
    button3 = new QPushButton("Button3", this);
    button4 = new QPushButton("Button4", this);

    button1->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, ButtonHeight*0), QSize(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight)));
    button2->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, ButtonHeight*1), QSize(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight)));
    button3->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, ButtonHeight*2), QSize(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight)));
    button4->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, ButtonHeight*3), QSize(ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight)));
}

int MainWindow::getButtonWidth()
{
    return ButtonWidth;
}

int MainWindow::getButtonHeight()
{
    return ButtonHeight;
}

int MainWindow::getButtonsNum()
{
    return ButtonsNum;
}
```

The files I have in `./src`:

- main.cpp
- mainwindow.cpp
- mainwindow.h
- proConfig.pro

Here's **proConfig.pro**:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = proConfig
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES +=  main.cpp \
            mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

I click **Build All** in eclipse and I get:

```
16:56:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project TestProject ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: Cross ARM C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O2  -g -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/Qt -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -c -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qmainwindow.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../src/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../src/main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qglobal.h:268:4: error: #error "Qt has not been ported to this OS - talk to qt-bugs@trolltech.com"
 #  error "Qt has not been ported to this OS - talk to qt-bugs@trolltech.com"
    ^
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1

16:56:23 Build Finished (took 469ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to compile my `c++` project with Cross ARM GCC in eclipse.
>
> I installed `GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-ins` (as described here), installed `libqt4-dev` by running `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`

This copy of `libqt4-dev` is for your host x86/x64 CPU. You cannot use it to cross-compile for your ARM CPU.

Use your Cross ARM GCC compiler to build Qt yourself. See https://forum.qt.io/topic/26540/how-can-i-cross-compile-qt-5-0 for example.

By the way, Qt 4 is very very old. It will no longer be supported after December 2015. I strongly suggest you use Qt 5 instead.